# Navigation bar not showing with MMDrawerController

Tags: swift, ios9, mmdrawercontroller

I am new to swift and iOS development.
In my project i am loading slidein menu with MMDrawerController, it works fine for slide ,but after initializing MMDrawerController in AppDelegate, by top navigation bar [navigation controller] is not getting displayed. commenting MMDrawer initialization shows the navigation bar and click events are firing proper , following is the navigation initialization code ,

```
func buildNavigationDrawer()
    {

            // Instantiate Main.storyboard
            let mainStoryBoard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle:nil)

            // Create View Controllers
            let mainPage:TabBarViewController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabBarViewController") as! TabBarViewController

            let leftSideMenu:LeftSideViewController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LeftSideViewController") as! LeftSideViewController

            let rightSideMenu:RightSideViewController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RightSideViewController") as! RightSideViewController



            // Wrap into Navigation controllers
            let leftSideMenuNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController:leftSideMenu)
            let rightSideMenuNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController:rightSideMenu)

            // Cerate MMDrawerController
            drawerContainer = MMDrawerController(centerViewController: mainPage, leftDrawerViewController: leftSideMenuNav, rightDrawerViewController: rightSideMenuNav)

            drawerContainer!.openDrawerGestureModeMask = MMOpenDrawerGestureMode.PanningCenterView
            drawerContainer!.closeDrawerGestureModeMask = MMCloseDrawerGestureMode.PanningCenterView

            // Assign MMDrawerController to our window's root ViewController
            window?.rootViewController = drawerContainer

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In one of the examples about the `MMDrawerController` there is this code:

```
 self.drawerController = [[MMDrawerController alloc]
                     initWithCenterViewController:navigationController....
```

Try to change your `mainPage` with a `UINavigationController` with the rootViewController linked to the `TabBarViewController` and you should be solve the issue.

**DETAIL**:

```
// Wrap into Navigation controllers
            let leftSideMenuNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController:leftSideMenu)
            let rightSideMenuNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController:rightSideMenu)
            let centerMenuNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainPage)

            // Cerate MMDrawerController
            drawerContainer = MMDrawerController(centerViewController: centerMenuNav, leftDrawerViewController: leftSideMenuNav, rightDrawerViewController: rightSideMenuNav)
```

Comment: can you explain a little bit more, or some codes .so I can try ..i am totally new to iOS

Comment: Sure, look my detail part.

Comment: awesome thanks a lot ...i been messing for over an hour :)